# C: undefined behavior fact

Tags: c, type-conversion

1) I have read many times about undefined behavior in C. That is about : some behavior that C doesn't say in its definition, so each compiler will have their implementation but not violate C standard. Example are : `x= ++y*4 + ++y*3`.

But, anyone here can give me two compiler that give different result ? I feel interested to test with it. (in my machine, I just have mingw)

2) And, C doesn't say about order of `+ - * /` operation. For example : `1*2 + 3 + 4*5`. `* /` will be calculate first, but we don't know its other.

So according to below example : if we have :

```
int a, b, c; 
// assign value for a,b,c
float result = a*b/c; // wrong
float result = (float)a*b/c; // seem true
```

But, `b/c` still can be calculate first, so the answer will be wrong. so, the true type-cast should be:

`float result = a*b/(float)c`

But, nearly, all books about C, all people coding C, always use : `(float)a*b/c` . Is it ALWAYS true, or they trust "normal compiler` will solve from left to right like we often think ?

Please give me clearer about this point.

Thanks :)

Comment: b/c can't calculate first -- multiplication and division have the same precedence and they're evaluated from left to right.

Comment: @H2CO3 If that true, why we don't have same thinking with `++` operator ?

Comment: operator precedence is well-defined: http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html

Comment: Why is `x= ++y*4 + ++y*3` important? Who writes code like that anyway?

Comment: Please don't place two questions in one.

Comment: @hqt because ++ again has a different precedence...

Comment: Operator precedence does not control order of evaluation (see 6.5/3).  And left-to-right evaluation is only guaranteed for a few operators (`||`, `&&`, `?:`, function-call `()`, and the comma operator).

Comment: @JohnBode: 6.5 3 says the order of evaluation of **subexpressions** is undefined. For example, in 1*2+3*4, the order in which 1*2 and 3*4 are evaluated is undefined. But precedence requires that both of those must be evaluated before the addition.

Comment: @EricPostpischil so, as you said, does it true that we should use `a*b/float(c)` rather than `(float)a*b/c`. Right ?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That's correct, but for something like `a*b/c`, it's not guaranteed that it will be evaluated as `(a*b)/c` vs. `a*(b/c)` AFAIK.

Comment: @JohnBode: `a*b/c` must be evaluated as `(a*b)/c`. Evaluating it as `a*(b/c)` violates precedence rules: 6.5 3 “The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax” (and footnote 72 explains left-to-right associativity is indicated by the syntax in subclauses) and the syntax for multiplicative operators in 6.5.5 shows the associativity is left-to-right (there must be a multiplicative-expression on the left and a cast-expression on the right, and “b/c” cannot be a cast-expression, so “c” must be a cast-expression, forcing “a*b” to be a multiplicative-expression, so “a*b” is first.

Comment: @hqt: `float(c)` is C++ and not C. `a*b/c` must be evaluated as if it were `(a*b)/c` and may not be evaluated as if it were `a*(b/c)`. `(float)a*b/c` is the same as `(((float)a)*b)/c`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) your are mixing up undefined behavior and unspecified behavior, they are not the same. 
This ugly expression that you give has undefined behavior; what you think are the consequences of undefined behavior is just unspecific behavior, namely that compilers chose one of different possibilities, which often is something that you can live with.

Undefined behavior can be much worse. If the behavior is undefined the compiler can generally chose anything to its liking, eat your lunch, empty your bank account, crash your computer. And unfortunately there are situations where compilers will do bad things that you don't expect in these cases. So just don't provoke UB in the first place.

Comment: It's "unspecified", not "unspecific". And the first example in the question does exhibit undefined behavior, because `y` is modified twice with no intervening sequence point.

Comment: @KeithThompson, yes I know. I was just referring to the OP's description what UB would be. I'll try to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two compilers to get different results from code with undefined behavior. In many (if not most) cases a single compiler will happily produce different results for you, if you change optimization settings and/or modify surrounding code.